# How do I merge local modifications with a git stash without an extra commit?

Tags: git

I stashed my changes to work on another task. When I finished the other task, I resumed work on the modifications I stashed, except that I forgot to `pop` them first. Now I have partially completed work both as local modifications and in the git stash. When I try to merge them using `git stash pop`, I get the following error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    file.js
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I would like git to merge the stashed changes locally before committing. I've tried searching around a bit for a solution but have come up empty so far.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to stage my local changes for commit prior to `git stash pop`, so I just did a `git add file.js` and then `git stash pop` and the merge proceeded as expected. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks, this helped indeed. One should then do a git reset HEAD . to unstage the changes (in my case it's often temporarily added debug output). So that's still 3 commands (add, pop, reset) instead of 1 (pop), I wish git would support popping into an unclean working directory.